# Calculate the area between a curve under a line and below this line

Tags: python, math, scipy, area

Hello,
Can anyone help me,how to calculate the area between a curve(I have the data, not the equation) and a line(linear regression for this curve).I need to do the summation of the area below and under this line.

I tried but it is only for the continuous curve!:

```
from scipy import integrate

def f(x):
    return x**2

integrate.quad(f, x0, x1)
```

How can I calculate the desired area?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13323861/6144626

Comment: Interesting to note that simps in scipy.integrate can used points which are not evenly distributed. See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html#scipy.integrate.simps)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is it is of much help, but if you only have the data for a set of points on the curve, you could look at using the Trapezium rule to generate a approximation of the are between the curve and the x-axis, provided you have a set of x and y values for points, using the SciPy library. You could then subtract the integral between the line and are. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps
from scipy import integrate
#Our arrays of coordinates
xs = np.array([1,3,4])
ys = np.array([5,7,3])
I1 = simps(ys, xs)
#The line now
def f(x):
    #sum linear equation
    return 4x+5
I2 = integrate.quad(f, 1, 4)#use are x bounds from the outermost curve points
I = I1-I2
```

(Derived from information [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html))