# How to find the area under the curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science, area

I am a beginner Python user.

There are two data files for the curve (x, y): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZB39G3SmtamjVjmLzkC2JefloZ9iShpO

How to find two areas under the curve, as shown in Figure: [image]

Black area (A) and red area (B)

I`m only know to how find total area:

```
from scipy.integrate import trapz

with open('./x_data.txt', 'rt') as f:
    x_file = f.read()

with open('./y_data.txt', 'rt') as f:
    y_file = f.read()

xlist = []
for line in x_file.split('\n'):
    if line: 
        xlist.append(float(line.strip()))
ylist = []
for line in y_file.split('\n'):
    if line: 
        ylist.append(float(line.strip()))

if len(xlist) != len(ylist):
    print(len(xlist), len(ylist))
    raise Exception('X and Y have different length')

xData = np.array(xlist)
yData = np.array(ylist)

area = trapz(y = yData, x = xData)
print("area =", area)
```

Comment: What defines (mathematically) where A ends and B starts?

Comment: It should be a 500 mark on the Y axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simpsons rule or the Trapezium rule to calculate the area under a graph given a table of y-values at a regular interval.

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
from numpy import trapz
```

reference: [Calculating the area under a curve given a set of coordinates, without knowing the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t)

Comment: OP is already using `trapz`.  I think he is asking how to split that area on a specific coordinate.

Comment: Yes, I understand that need to integrate from 0 to the value where Y = 500. But it is not clear how to point to that string in the file with the values.

Comment: I know that Y=500 its 154 string in y_data.txt file. So i need integrate from bottom string to 154?

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to give the sequence, if I didn't read is wrong from the documentation. Hope it helps.