# Integrate the area under many points in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to integrate the area under many points, not a curve (I only find methods to integrate the area under curves).

Is there any method that I can achieve this? Maybe using numpy or matplotlib?

Thank you for your help in advance.

This is my data set figure looks like. I want to integrate the area under these points.

[image]

These are the data points.

[0.00000000e+00 1.37130515e-16 1.90336717e-16 2.28664207e-16
 2.58927168e-16 2.83813929e-16 3.04723233e-16 3.22492459e-16
 3.37665111e-16 3.50609398e-16 3.61576102e-16 3.70726154e-16
 3.78137929e-16 3.83792014e-16 3.87510361e-16 3.88742340e-16
 3.85351187e-16 2.78698453e-16 2.29699156e-16 2.03500270e-16
 1.85800329e-16 1.72670685e-16 1.62403486e-16 1.54093438e-16
 1.47201608e-16 1.41381359e-16 1.36396976e-16 1.32081274e-16
 1.28311691e-16 1.24995947e-16 1.22063031e-16 1.19457285e-16
 1.17134410e-16 1.15058687e-16 1.13200992e-16 1.11537358e-16
 1.10047903e-16 1.08716034e-16 1.07527829e-16 1.06471570e-16
 1.05537375e-16 1.04716905e-16 1.04003142e-16 1.03390204e-16
 1.02873204e-16 1.02448132e-16 1.02111771e-16 1.01861621e-16
 1.01695853e-16 1.01613266e-16 1.01613266e-16 1.01695853e-16
 1.01861621e-16 1.02111771e-16 1.02448132e-16 1.02873204e-16
 1.03390204e-16 1.04003142e-16 1.04716905e-16 1.05537375e-16
 1.06471570e-16 1.07527829e-16 1.08716034e-16 1.10047903e-16
 1.11537358e-16 1.13200992e-16 1.15058687e-16 1.17134410e-16
 1.19457285e-16 1.22063031e-16 1.24995947e-16 1.28311691e-16
 1.32081274e-16 1.36396976e-16 1.41381359e-16 1.47201608e-16
 1.54093438e-16 1.62403486e-16 1.72670685e-16 1.85800329e-16
 2.03500270e-16 2.29699156e-16 2.78698453e-16 3.85351187e-16
 3.88742340e-16 3.87510361e-16 3.83792014e-16 3.78137929e-16
 3.70726154e-16 3.61576102e-16 3.50609398e-16 3.37665111e-16
 3.22492459e-16 3.04723233e-16 2.83813929e-16 2.58927168e-16
 2.28664207e-16 1.90336717e-16 1.37130515e-16 0.00000000e+00]

Comment: You can already think of each point as representing the height of a rectangle with unit width. Just sum the points.

Comment: There are different ways to integrate.  First choose your method.  See, for example, https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/riemann-sums-4715. You also need an x-axis (each point should have both an _x_ and _y_ coordinate).

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t, assuming that the x values are simply the integers [0, 1, ..., 99].

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I need!!!