# Calculating area under the curve in python for two given arrays:

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, auc

I'm using the following code to graph a DF/F signal. I'm hoping to be able to calculate the area under the curve for y = ch1dff and any
given x (downsamp_time) range as the limit. I can't seem to find ant code that allows for integration without a function. [See plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RepHV.png)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(downsamp_time, ch1dff , color='g',label= '465 nm DF/F',)
plt.legend()
plt.xlim([2154, 2334])

markers = m
for marker in markers:
    plt.axvline(x=marker,alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just can't seem to be able to find any code or package that lets you integrate a curve without a given function. Both "downsamp_time" and "ch1dff" are 1D arrays.

Comment: If you didn’t find any code, what is stopping you from writing it yourself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t