# PYTHON: how to calculate the area under the curves stored in an array of object?

Tags: python, arrays, area

I have an array of object with size (22, 2) for Y axis, and the corresponding x-axis is an array of object with size (22, 2) as well. I need to calculate the Area between the curve y = f(x), and the x-axis, for each array.
I wrote this code:

```
Area = np.trapz(y,x)
```

I got an array of object in which each module consists of many elements, but I expected to get a single value (area) for each y=f(x).

How can I calculate correctly the area for each function f(x) stored in the array of object?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t

Comment: The input arrays are 2-dimensional (size (22, 2)).  To get a scalar output from `trapz` your inputs will have to be 1-dimensional arrays.  Is it possible that one of your input arrays contains both `x` and `y` in its columns?

Comment: the 2-dimensional input arrays (22,2) consists of two columns: the first column is `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` and it's just an index column; whareas in the second column, each element contains an array (corresponding to Y). To overcome the problem you said, I selected the second column only, andt it works now! Thank you.
`Area_t=np.trapz(X[1,:],Y[1,:])`
Then, I compared that results with that coming from `scipy.integrate` and I have the same values.