# How to find a Area Under the Curve from number of datas from the excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, plot, curve-fitting, area

I am completely unaware of

[image]

How to find the area under the curve using Python. The attached figure shows what I am looking for. I need to plot the graph, which has more than 6000 points, and then need to measure the area in the RED and GREEN regions. Can anyone help with this matter?

Comment: Here's a start. Find all alrea. Find green. Then red = all - green. Do you know the trapezoid rule? Also, I would think you could do it entirely in Excel (at least the area part), but I guess that's not the task.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said, you can use the trapezoid rule. Numpy has a function for that.
Here is a little example from an other question: [Calculating the area under a curve given a set of coordinates, without knowing the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t)