Calculating the area under a curve confining to a region and without knowing the function
I have data points (x and y values) for the blue and black graphs shown in the image. I do not know the functions of the blue and black graphs.

If I know the x1 and x2 coordinates (as shown in the image), how do I calculate the area under the blue line confining to the x coordinates between x1 and x2. Can anyone provide me an example of using numpy and scipy libraries to perform the job with the composite trapezoidal (numpy.trapz) and Simpson's (scipy.integrate.simpson) rules. I am new to python. I appreciate your help in this regard.
Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t

@Gооd_Mаn Thank you very much for sharing the previous discussion, which is similar to my question. However, I do not understand where to put my x-values and y-values in the given script.  Would be able to mention it?

Did you opened the documentation for trapz which is provided in the link? It seems pretty straightforward to me once you read it while I never used such a function...

You might need to first interpolate one of the function though if the x values are not matching between the two.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you add your data as a link (no screenshot).

@jlandercy                                                                                                                                  For blue line (.xvg file) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZyjOWbNH0Yv4oweq55sKJhHPw3nGKXA_/view?usp=drive_link                                                                                                                                                       For black line (.xvg file) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncuueaLXe9PxXcyWm9Mb_RixBX4e-ETJ/view?usp=drive_link

First we load your files:
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

def load(file):
    with open(file, "r") as handler:
        raw = handler.readlines()[24:]
    data = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("".join(raw)), header=None, names=["x", "y"])
    return data

pol = load("pol_2000.xvg")
sol = load("sol_2000.xvg")

We find the curve intersection (after checking they are equally sampled):
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(sol.y - pol.y))).flatten()
sel = slice(idx[0], idx[1] + 1)

Intersection occurs at:
xl = sol.x[idx]
# 15      0.839916
# 239    12.978100

Now it is sufficient to integrate over the selection:
I = integrate.simpson(sol.y[sel], x=sol.x[sel])
# 3026.198371039349

Graphically it renders as follow:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(sol.x, sol.y, label="Sol")
axe.plot(pol.x, pol.y, label="Pol")
axe.fill_between(sol.x[sel], sol.y[sel], alpha=0.4, label="A = %.2f" % I)
axe.legend()
axe.grid()


